# How make saveAll with jparepository with no delete only updates or insert?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want a function that massively updates and inserts data for better performance.
And I don't want to delete everything, like the default saveAll function.
And above all the function must not change the creation date.

saveAll(list changeOrNewOjects)

```java
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Dom {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    // more attribute
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Date dateCreation;
    //Getter and setter
    // contuctors
    }



}
public interface  DomRepository extends CrudRepository<Dom, String> {
}
```

database.dom -> 2500 rows

`lstDomData.size()` -> 154

`domServices.savAll(lstDomData);`

database.dom -> 154 rows

Comment: The `saveAll` method does not delete anything, it only saves(insert or updates) whatever is in the `Iterable` you pass as an argument. Also, what do you mean by "creation date"? If it's a field in the Database, you simply do not modify it in your code. What have you tried? How did you come to the conclusion that `saveAll` deletes anything? More details would be helpful.

Comment: I have fewer rows after my second call from my batch